# Utilities function in Google App Scripts not working

Tags: google-apps-script, simpledateformat, date-formatting

Function `Utilities.formatDate` in Google App Scripts is not working correct for date in year 2013

**Example-**

```
date = Tue Dec 31 2013 18:43:12 GMT+0530 (IST)

after formatting it in YYYYMMdd format
```

**using code-**

```
Utilities.formatDate(date, "IST" ,"YYYYMMdd"))

result was- 20**14**1231
```

In the above result year is expected to be 2013 as per above mentioned date.

The same code is working correct for date in 2012 and 2014.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just change your pattern from YYYY to yyyy (lower case) and it will work, check [this](https://script.google.com/macros/d/17P7cxFG1VFUIKluIRdTIhnsGH0SxPV4JHxVtdm3qWd8PawF-9RjrLzFc/edit?template=default&folder=0B0kQD4hSd4KASUJKb2cya0NET1U&usp=drive_web):

```
function myFunction() {
  var date = new Date("Tue Dec 31 2013 18:43:12 GMT+0530 (IST)");

//after formatting it in YYYYMMdd format
  var format = Utilities.formatDate(date,"IST", "yyyyMMdd");

  Logger.log(format);
}
```