# one second = 1 year for 12/31/2017 using Utilities.formatDate

Tags: javascript, date, google-apps-script, simpledateformat, date-formatting

Have curious results converting date using `Utilities.formatDate()`

```
function test_date_conversion_1() {
    var in_d_str = "12/31/2017"
    var new_d = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(in_d_str), "EET", "MM/dd/YYYY")
    return new_d
} 
// new_d = "12/31/2018"  2018?!
```

I've tried to develop a patch and get unexpected results for this function

```
function test_date_conversion(offset) {
    //offset = 1
    var in_d_str = "12/31/2017"
    var in_d = new Date(in_d_str)
    var in_d_epoch = in_d.getTime()
    var in_d_epoch_dep_1 = in_d_epoch+offset
    var in_d_d_dep_1 = new Date(in_d_epoch_dep_1)
    var new_d = Utilities.formatDate(in_d_d_dep_1, "EET", "MM/dd/YYYY")
}
```

if offset = 1 then new_d = "12/31/2018"

if offset = (-1) then new_d = "12/30/2017"

so 1 milisecond = 1 year?

EET = GMT+2 = script timezone

worksheet timezone  = GMT+3

from debugger i've noticed that date is spoiled by Utilities.formatDate()
[image]

I've triede +/-1h, +/-1h+/-1sec offsets and still can't get just 12/31/2017 from 12/31/2017.

I've patched it like this

```
if (new_d == "12/31/2018")
    new_d = "12/31/2017";
```

but look for solid solution.
thank you for answer in adwance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Utilities function in Google App Scripts not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20884766/utilities-function-in-google-app-scripts-not-working)

Comment: Please don't use the built-in parser for date strings (timestamps). Use a decent library that includes a parser where you can specify the format to parse.

Comment: yes. my question is the same issue.  I didn't find it.
decent libraries  are for sure the  best for Javascript on front end. I'll google if it possible to connect decent library to GScript.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The third parameter of [`formatDate(date, timeZone, format)`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/utilities/utilities#formatDate(Date,String,String)) is

> a format per the **SimpleDateFormat** specification

For the [SimpleDateFormat](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) you use `Y` for the week year and `y` for the year. Since the week of `12/31/2017` is the first week of 2018, it will show as 2018.

Instead of using `"MM/dd/YYYY"`, use `"MM/dd/yyyy"`.